# Do you need an App to use Sign in with Apple on website?

Tags: sign-in-with-apple

We want to be able to use [Sign in with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/) feature, but we don't have an app yet, just a website.

There's confusing, unclear information in their docs.
When I try and go through the process, we get stuck as it asks for an AppID, but there's no statement on their site, about needed an app to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do need an app.

"To test your website, you’ll need to group it with an app that is enabled for Sign in with Apple and is available on the App Store"

https://developer.apple.com/sign-in-with-apple/get-started/